# How to run xdebug on win xp

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

I have little problem with xdebug installation on winxp. I paste output from php info into form on xdebug pages, and then install required version o dll lib. Problem is that I cannot connect to xdebug on port 9000, becouse nothing listen on port 9000 (I found it by netstat -a command). Can someone please give me the point how to solve this issue? Thanks.
Here is output of my phpinfo :

http://pastebin.com/472SaQKv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have allready solved this issue. Here is configuration in my php.ini and it runs!

```
zend_extension="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.3-5.3-vc9.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=ON
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=ON
xdebug.remote_log="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\xdebug.log"

xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:/Windows/Temp/xdebug"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:/Windows/Temp/xdebug"
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an actual debugger listening on port 9000. [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/docs.php) offers XDebug compatibility, for instance.

The following needs to be adjusted in your php.ini:

```
 ; Enable remote connections
 xdebug.remote_enable = On

 ; Automatically connect when PHP script starts
 xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

 ; IP adress to connect *to*
 ; (adjust accordingly)
 xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
```

These settings will make `XDebug` connect to localhost whenever a PHP script is launched. If set up correctly*, Eclipse will ask you if you'd like to accept a debugging connection.

* see tutorials in link above